# Excel VBA - open a workbook and pasting data

Tags: excel, vba

I found this excellent code however I need to adapt it for my purposes.

Firstly I need to open a data workbook that is on our network. The problem I have is that it is likely at times to be open by another user and will offer the option of "read only". How can I get it to accept the read-only option so that I can commence extracting the data.

Secondly it copies using the "=" . How can I change it to copy just the values?

First macro:

```
Sub test()
'to open another workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Schedule.xls"
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

2nd Macro:

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Newsh As Worksheet
Dim myCell As Range
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim RwNum As Long
Dim Basebook As Workbook

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Delete the sheet "Summary-Sheet" if it exist
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-Sheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a worksheet with the name "Summary-Sheet"
Set Basebook = ThisWorkbook
Set Newsh = Basebook.Worksheets.Add
Newsh.Name = "Summary-Sheet"

'The links to the first sheet will start in row 2
RwNum = 1

For Each Sh In Basebook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> Newsh.Name And Sh.Visible Then
        ColNum = 1
        RwNum = RwNum + 1
        'Copy the sheet name in the A column
        Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = Sh.Name

        For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A1,D5:E5,Z10")  '<--Change the range
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
            "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
        Next myCell

    End If
Next Sh

Newsh.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always open the workbook as read-only if you are only extracting data.
Instead of using .formula use .value

Comment: Thank you Jason. Could I please ask you how to merge both macro's so that the data workbook is opened for data extraction and then c losed not saving any changes.